# Animation using UIButton

Tags: xcode, animation, uibutton

How I can move my uiimageview while I keep on pressing the uibutton? the old code is like you have to press 2 or 3 times to move again and the long press isn't working since it is touch up inside.

```
-(IBAction) MoveRightButton : (id) sender {

[self animateRight];
[self rightTimer];

}

-(IBAction) stopRight {

[image stopAnimating];
[rightTimer invalidate];
}

-(void) animateRight {
with animateRight images and start animating.
}

-(void) goRight {
[UIView animateWithDuration : 0.5 animation : ^{
image.frame = CGRectMake (image.frame.origin.x + 10, image.frame.origin.y,image.frame.size.width, image.frame.size.height);
}];
[self stopRight];
}

-(void) rightTimer {
rightTimer = [some NSTimer with selector of (goright)];
```

Answer (score 0):

try mapping this action

```
UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat instead of UIControlEventTouchUpInside
```

to  method

> -(IBAction) MoveRightButton : (id) sender

Comment: i dont think it work coz there is some choice in xib editor where u can choose touch up inside also there is touchdownrepeat n i checked it but didnt worked.i exactly didnt find a real solution for this.

Comment: you should rather just change the frame than animation on touchdown repeat event

Answer (score 0):

Create two IBAction methods for your UIButton using sent events;

**Touch Down** - The associated method will be called when the button is *first pressed*.

**Touch Up Inside** - The associated method will be called when the button is *released*.

So in the "Touch Down" method, begin the animation as you have it, and in the "Touch Up Inside" method - stop it using something like:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

[myView.layer removeAllAnimations];
```

---

EDIT:

**(1)** View your **.xib**, and create a UIButton.

**(2)** Hold *"alt"* down and click your **.h** file. 
This'll bring up that file in the assistant editor - but will enable you to still work on the xib.

**(3)** Hold down *"ctrl"*, and then click-drag from the UIButton to the **.h** file (below @interface).

**(4)** In the resulting pop-up, select "*Action*" in the *connection* field and name your method. The *event* field contains many options, of which you're interested in **Touch Down** and **Touch Up Inside**. Choose one, and click connect.

**(5)** Repeat for the event you didn't do in **(4)** (but obviously change the name). Those methods will have automatically been created in your **.m** file so go there and edit them as you please!

Comment: thanks for the answer but exactly dont understand how to implement the touchDown and touchUpInside as u said

Comment: Edited the answer - hopefully that helps but shout again if it doesn't!

Comment: Hey okami i know how to make the actions and buttons and connections. I dont know how to imPlement it man. Tried many solutions but couldnt. Thanks for support

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have the action methods "Touch Down" and "Touch Up Inside" created? 
If so, just put the UIView animation in the touch down method, and the code snippet I gave above in the touch up inside method (obviously replacing myView to appropriate name).

Comment: Hey okami trying to figure out the codes but not much luck, now i have uibutton named leftbutton. How can i implement touch down and repeat to fire the timer repeatedly to move my uiimage while pressing the button? And terminate timer in touch end